# How to stop objects from second layer createing themselves

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

I have a script that adds an object at a random choice of predefined coordinates.  The script works just fine, but as with the other objects that are being added by the empty that contains this script, another instance of the object is created in the same place as the first enemy and health objects.  I can't find anywhere in my code where it says to add these objects from the second layer.  My question is how can I either make the first instances of these objects automatically delete themselves, or, make the objects not appear in the first place.  Here is the [.blend](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5Rj7h_MP4waU0ZWd3QxX2I2QUk&authuser=0) (to see the problem, view from the top middle of the map.  Thanks!

Comment: It is hard to tell what your problem is in this specific case based on the details given. Please upload your blend file using a service such as http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Well I was going to say that.

Comment: This is sooo confusing.

Comment: @Anson there are no doubles in the file , it creates one object at a time ?

Comment: @Chebhou No, there are no duplicate objects, the enemies are created one every second, and the icosphere object is supposed to be created only once, with an "Always">Tap sensor.  The health object is created every 30 seconds or so.

Comment: @AnsonSavage so what is wrong with this file ?

Comment: @Chebhou , the objects from the second layer that are being added by the empty object in the game are all being added around the center of the game without being told to.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem.  I just handled the problem locally in the Icosphere rather than controlling it with the Empty.  Thanks!